# PowerApps Multiple Collections into one collection with AddColumns LookUp joins

Tags: powerapps

I have the following select that I am trying to replicate in a Power Apps gallery.

```
SELECT 
      colTechFees.[Year]
      ,colBuyer.FullName
      ,colTechFees.[ReviewCompleted]
      ,colSupplier.ParentTechSupplier
      ,colTechFees.[PriorYearSpend]
      ,colTechFees.[CurrentYearSpend]
      ,colTechFees.[ProjectedSpend]
      ,colTechFees.[CurrentTechFee]
      ,colTechFees.[PriorYearTechFee]
      ,colTechFees.[ChangeNew]
      ,colTechFees.[BuyerAdjustedFee]
      ,colTechFees.[FinalFee]
      ,colTechFees.[AdjustmentReason]
      ,colTechFees.[TechFeeReceivedAmt]
      ,colTechFees.[DateReceived]
      ,colTechFees.[TechFeeCollectionComment]
      ,colSupCntct.FirstName
      ,colSupCntct.LastName
      ,colSupCntct.JobTitle
      ,colSupCntct.PrimaryEmail
      ,colSupCntctToo.PrimaryEmail
  FROM [BrandSupplierTechFees] as colTechFees
  inner join [Contact] as colBuyer on colTechFees.BuyerContactId = colBuyer.ContactID
  inner join [BrandSupplier] as colSupplier on colTechFees.BrandSupplierId =  colSupplier.BrandSupplierID
  inner join [Contact] as colSupCntct on colTechFees.SupplierContactId =  colSupCntct.ContactID
  left outer join [Contact] as colSupCntctToo on colTechFees.SupplierContactCopyAlsoId =  colSupCntctToo.ContactID
```

I have created collections in the OnVisible for my screen:

```
ClearCollect(colBuyer,ShowColumns(Filter(Contact,CompanyName="QSCC"),"ContactID","FullName"));
ClearCollect(colSupplier,ShowColumns(BrandSupplier,"BrandSupplierID","ParentTechSupplier"));
ClearCollect(colSupCntct,ShowColumns(Contact,"ContactID","PrimaryEmail","FirstName","LastName","JobTitle"));
ClearCollect(colSupCntctToo,ShowColumns(Contact,"ContactID","PrimaryEmail"));
ClearCollect(colTechFees,BrandSupplierTechFees);

ClearCollect(colSolution,
    AddColumns(colTechFees As _tab1,        
        "AllColumns",LookUp(colSupCntct,ContactID=_tab1.SupplierContactId,FirstName)               
    )
);
```

I am trying to do all of the "joins" into my colSolution collection.

I am stuck on 3 things:

1. Multple AddColumns/Lookups in 1 collection
2. How to return all of the columns from colSupCntct in the AddColumns/Lookup
3. How to approximate a left outer join

Any help is much apprectiated.